# php mail() doesn't send Email with TLD .one

Tags: php, email, dns, smtp

has any body experience with mail() function of PHP in case of issues with new top level domains like ".one" ?

`mail('name@domain.one', 'Description', 'Mesage', null,
   '-fwebmaster@example.com');`

This email never be send to his recipient. 
Other emails like .com are no problem.

Comment: `mail()` does not send mail. Your email server sends the mail

Comment: Are you testing on local machine? Do you have SMTP server set up?

Comment: no, php is run on a webserver and smtp is working fine with other tld like .com or .nl ... only .one doesn't work

Comment: If you can send it to .com email addresses and not .one email addresses can make sure that you can actually send an email to that .one email address using something like gmail or any other email client. If that does not work the issue might be at the other end.

Comment: Install sendmail on your machine

Comment: Can you please confirm that the email sending through gmail worked  or not, so we can look further if needed?